# Any way to find the reply codes for sending mails in exchangelib

Tags: exchangewebservices, exchangelib

Example : How smtp has different reply code 510/511 : Bad email address.

Is there a way in exchangelib to catch such sort of exceptions as well?

Answer (score 0):

exchangelib doesn't actually send the email, the Exchange server does that. If the email address is internal, you can look it up beforehand using `Account.protocol.resolve_names()`. For external email addresses, you'll have to monitor any error emails that the remote email server sends as response to an invalid email address.